# Windows 10: How can I keep toast notifications (balloons) on screen when I am far from my computer?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

**Windows 10** dismisses toast notifications (balloons on notification area, near the clock) after the defined period even when I am not using my computer:

[image: Toast Notification]

This is not the **behavior on Windows 7**, where whenever the operating system thinks I am **not using the computer**, notifications **stay on screen** until I come back to it (i.e: mouse moving, key pressed... etc).

I know I can change the *duration* of the notification on screen up to 5 minutes, but that is not what I need, because I could stay far of my computer for longer.

How can I **configure Windows 10** toast notifications to **behave like** they did on Windows 7?

Comment: within the Settings you can set how long the notifications appears.  However, the applications themselves, can also change that behavior if they want.

Comment: If you have Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education, you may be able to find at least a partial solution by utilizing the `Local Group Policy Editor` and configuring the policy to [Disable showing balloon notifications as toasts](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-disable-toast-notifications-and-enable-classic-balloon-tips/).  I tried it myself and [verified that it still works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzrWV.jpg) in Windows 10 Version 1709, but you will need to test it yourself to see if the balloon tip duration meets your criteria.

Comment: @Run5k : does this cheat change the behavior to not dismiss when computer is not in use, or is it just a visual change in the appearance of balloons?

Comment: That's a good question, and I haven't had the opportunity to test it extensively.  As I said before, you are probably the ideal person to test it and see if it suits your needs.  Remember that there isn't anything to install... it is a native Windows configuration, so it is as harmless as possible.  On top of that, there is certainly no rush involved:  we are here to help *you,* and if you discover that this Group Policy setting actually does work like the legacy Balloon Tips within Windows 7, the entire community will benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thanks to Run5k for the [link](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-disable-toast-notifications-and-enable-classic-balloon-tips/).

A possible solution, if you don't mind to revert to the appearance of old Windows 7 balloons, is enable **classic ballons**:

[image: Old and new balloons]

1.- Run `gpedit.msc`.

2.- Open the tree `User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar`.

3.- On right pane double-click on **Disable showing balloon notifications as toasts** option and set it to **Enabled**.

My Windows 10 required **rebooting** (at least for `Explorer` process) to apply changes.
This change is **reversible** using same method.

**Further notes**:

If you don't have Group Policy Editor (Gpedit.msc), you can simply set the **registry** key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\EnableLegacyBalloonNotifications` to 1 (create it, type DWORD, if it does not already exist).

Now the behavior of balloons (not just the appearance) will be the same you had on Windows 7.